# Refactoring - Extract Method Object in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring

While doing refactoring in Netbeans I am stuck in a problem. I am not able to find the "Extract Method Object" option in Netbeans which helps to extract a class from a method [Like the Intellij Idea Option mentioned in this link https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/extract-method-object.html ] . Is there any alternative option to this?

[image: Refactoring Option in Netbeans]

Comment: If the class already exists you can Move the method.

Comment: That mean, we do not have any direct way in extracting class from method?

Answer (score 4):

[image]You can use the option Refactor / Introduce / Method in order to extract a selected portion of method to a new method in same class, thats like Intellij Idea option. See the picture below:

[Refactor / Introduce / Method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LitqH.png)

Comment: its better to repost the pic in your answer.